# How to fix `Ambiguous use of 'subscript'` every time?

Tags: swift2

I'm using [this class](https://github.com/KaanEmec/SpotifySearch) that was written in `Swift 1.2` and now I want to use it with `Swift 2.0`.

I get an error: `Ambiguous use of 'subscript'` @ `let artist = result["name"] as! String`

```
                    } else if let jsonArtists = jsonResult["artists"] as? NSDictionary {
                    if let results:NSArray = jsonArtists["items"] as? NSArray {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            self.searching = false
                            var suggestionResults: [spotifySearchResult] = []
                            for result in results {
                                let artist = result["name"] as! String
                                var sugresult = spotifySearchResult()
                                sugresult.artist = artist
                                if !suggestionResults.contains(sugresult) {
                                    suggestionResults.append(sugresult)
                                }
                            }
                            handler(suggestionResults)
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
```

I tried different fixes such as `let artist = (result["name"] as! String)` or `let artist = (result["name"] as! String) as! String`
But nothing worked.

I know that the question was already post 4 times but, I can't find anyone explaining how to fix it in every case, only case by case.

Can someone explain me how to investigate to fix it? Not just only a fix for my case. I would prefer fix it by myself with your hints!

BTW what does mean `subscript`? Is subscript the thing between quotation mark? IMHO the error message is a bit vague...

EDIT:

```
class spotifySearchResult : NSObject {
var artist=""
var track=""
var duration=0
var spotifyURL = NSURL()
var spotifyURI = NSURL()

override func isEqual(theObject: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if let myObject = theObject as? spotifySearchResult {
        return (myObject.artist.uppercaseString == self.artist.uppercaseString && myObject.track.uppercaseString == self.track.uppercaseString)
    }
    return false
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscription means to use the shorter syntax `item["key"]` for `item.objectForKey["key"]`

`results` seems to be an array of dictionaries so I suggest to cast down to a more specific type

```
if let results = jsonArtists["items"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
```

or even, if all values are guaranteed to be strings

```
if let results = jsonArtists["items"] as? [[String:String]] {
```

Comment: Hi @vadian, thanks for your answer but that's not working, and I really would like to understand how to "debug" this. BTW thanks for the `subscript` explanation

Comment: Maybe the reason is that `spotifySearch` is not Swift 2 compatible. Did you check that?

Comment: I edited my question, adding `spotifySearch` class, what do you mean not compatible?

Comment: The SpotifySearch class on GitHub is not compatible with Swift2. it needs to be updated for example to the new error handling syntax